# grab URL parameters with special characters

Tags: php, urlencode, html-entities

I am grabbing the parameters from the URL using the following:

```
<?php echo $_GET['compname']; ?>
```

I just noticed that some of the parameters include special characters, so I tried using the following:

```
<?php echo urlencode($_GET['compname']); ?>
```

But the output looks like this:

```
COMPANYNAME+LLC+LTD
```

If the company name has special characters (ex: COMPANY & SONS), the output will look like this:

```
COMPANY+
```

I tried using HTMLENTITIES like this:

```
<?php echo urlencode(htmlentities($_GET['compname'])); ?>
```

But I get the same results

```
COMPANY+
```

I tried to utilize examples from the following website:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php echo urlencode(htmlentities($_GET['compname'], ENT_QUOTES)); ?>
```

But I'm getting the same results:

```
COMPANY+
```

I need to get the results to look like this:

```
COMPANY & SONS
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$_GET['compname']="this+is+a+test+for+you";
echo urldecode($_GET['compname']); // decode this is a test for you
?>
```

Read more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: I'm no longer getting the + symbols, but I'm not getting any other special characters.

Comment: Does your URL encoded string look like this ? COMPANY+%26+SONS

Comment: It actually looks something like this:  JAY%20FARO%20&%20CO

Comment: I'm actually using your example above, with only urldecode.  My output looks like "JAY FARO " with a space at the end, no &, and the CO cut off.

Comment: That works when I hard coded the URL value.  But when I try to grab the URL value with $_GET, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Check your code previous to your URL encode and make sure its not been altered by something else then. Echo the $_GET['compname'] before the decode to verify, or post the full code to your question I can check for you.

Comment: I'm only doing the following: <input type="hidden" id="getCompanyName" value="<?php echo $_GET['companyname']; ?>" /> , which is grabbing the company name from the URL.

Comment: The issue is with the GET data isnt properly encoded URL should be JAY+FARO+%26+CO. Show the form your using to post this data please.

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to say thank you for helping me out.  As far as my problem is concerned, I am not using a form.  I am just using hidden inputs to grab the URL parameters, to which I use JQuery to set them into their variables.  On a previous page, I build the URL with JQuery, so maybe I need to somehow decode/encode when I create the URL.  Not sure.

Comment: I already attempt that before you suggested it, albeit with no success.  At this point, I'm about to tell my DBA to update everything that has an ampersand to the word 'and'.  I'll have to revisit this later.  I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry bud its 

<script>
var test  = encodeURI("JAY FARO & CO");
alert(test);
</script>

<?php
echo urldecode("JAY%20FARO%20&%20CO"); 
?>

Comment: I went ahead and had my DBA update the column to remove any special characters.  Really not what I wanted to do, but I was spending too much time on this problem. Thank you for your help.  I may have to revisit this issue.

Comment: @John Beasley You need to use encodeURI and not encodeuricomponent on your jquery part.